# Exporting Sublime Text configuration and installed packages

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have spent considerable time to tune up Sublime Text 2 configs. Now I would want to share my configurations (one file) and installed packages list with my friend. What would be the best way to do this? Manually pick related folders in Packages and zip them or something else? Preferably I'd like to create an automated script which could be copy-pasted to my friend and others.

My friend is using Linux. I am using OSX, which may cause some extra problems.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you are using Package Control, send your friend `Package Control.sublime-settings`. In fact, the easiest way to transfer settings between machines is to move the `User` package between machines. This, in combination with package control, makes setting up on a new machine relatively quick and painless. The only issues your friend might have is mismatched key binding or other system specific settings. These files have the notation `some_name (platform).extension`. Other than that, I wouldn't forsee any issues (unless you are using OS X specific plugins).

Comment: How to bootstrap package download on the target machine?

Comment: Install `Package Control`. Place the `User` folder containing `Package Control.sublime-settings`. Start ST. Shouldn't have to do anything beyond that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works very well! Blogged about this in more detail http://opensourcehacker.com/2013/05/09/exporting-and-sharing-sublime-text-configuration/

Comment: Shove the `User` folder as folks noted, into a private repository. This way you can keep track of changes on each machine and even have branches per OS/platform. Due to work specificity I have to have a whole array of options so I'd have a central place where to bootstrap the download from (the repo) and then, probably, push platform-specific files under a tag or new branch when leaving the environment.

Comment: I have a backup system with all the files, where can I find this folder on disk?

Comment: @pal4life, the structure varies depending on your system. In you local ST install, you can go to Preferences -> Browse Packages. This should allow you to see where it is on your local system. You should then be able to use that to map to where it is in your backup.

Answer (score 5):

Package control has a good doc talking about how to sync Sublime settings and install packages: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing

Answer (score 0):

**Using Windows**

Open a new `Command Prompt` and type the following at the command line:

`cd "C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages" dir`

Then copy and paste to an editor (e.g. Sublime Text) and filter out the relevant parts. Not great but working.