# How can I install multiple sublime text 3 packages with a single bundle?

Tags: sublimetext3

I've installed 20 packages of sublime text 3 for front-end development so far. I want to know that is there any possibility to make all these 20 packages into 1 single file or 1 core package or something like that so that I can install only 1 file rather than installing 20 packages next time? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite new to ST3 so... I believe all you have to do is save your packages directory.  http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html
Look for "restore" toward the bottom of that page.

Preferences->Browse Packages. For my win7 machine it's:
C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages

I've copied that directory to other pc's (ubuntu, win7, xp [appropriate location for each]) and it worked fine for the most part, though you may find you have to do a little tweaking afterward.

Probably best to follow this advice: Copy the "User" directory.  [Exporting Sublime Text configuration and installed packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412678/exporting-sublime-text-configuration-and-installed-packages)