# What is a good Sublime Text workflow for sharing a common setup between several platforms

Tags: editor, cross-platform, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using Windows, Mac and Linux machines in my daily duties. On all machines, I program in C++ and various shells scripts. So far I've adopted the various "main" IDEs on each platform, but the diversity is irritating. I'm therefore looking into the possibility of using Sublilme Text on all platforms.

I have a setup of Sublime Text on Windows that works perfectly and would like to use the same on the other platforms also, so that when I change something in my Sublime setup on, say, my Mac, I can easily pick up the latest setup on my Windows machine the next time I'm there.

Is this possible on the 3 mentioned platforms, without getting (more) grey hair? If so, any suggestions or experiences thereof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many folks upload the "Packages/User" folder to GitHub (or your VCS service of choice). Then, they use [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) to install their packages. Package control, through a settings file, will install any missing packages on a particular machine. I wrote a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16412678/exporting-sublime-text-configuration-and-installed-packages/16414529?noredirect=1#comment46490953_16414529).  You would then clone the git repo onto each machine, pulling updates when you decide to change something.

Alternatively, you could probably use a cloud service + symlinks to keep things auto synced, but I've personally never used it that way.

There are some plugins that are platform specific, so keep an eye out for those.

Answer (score 0):

There's also the Package [Package Syncing](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Package%20Syncing), which syncs installed packages and settings via some cloud service.

Works quite nicely, and automatically.

Has the advantage that you don't have to push/pull some dotfiles repo all the time.

No idea though whether this will work seamlessly across platforms (meaning whether all the settings will be platform-independent).